# Por qué aparece el texto antes?

Tags: javascript

```js
/*      Multiple methods in arrays

  Learning javascript and reinforcing
  my knowledge!

      ====> Eduardo Sebastián <====
*/

// Re-usable var's
var cc = []; // Main array
var div = document.getElementById('array');
var t = "";
var w = "";
var c = "";

// End 

// Add element at first w/ push()
div.addEventListener("click", pushing);
function pushing() {
for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  cc.push(i);
 w = document.getElementById("array");
 c = document.createElement("B");
 c.style.color = "white";
 c.style.textAlign = "center";
 var lastc = w.childNodes[2];
 t = document.createTextNode((i==0 ? "Push in array:" : "" )+i);
 c.appendChild(t);
 w.insertBefore(c, lastc); 

  
}
  }
```

```css
body {  
  background-color: #E8A623;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: white;
 }

#array {
  
  background-color: pink;
  width: 320px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Push() array</h3>
     <h3 style="text-align: center;">Shift() array</h3>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Solo quiero saber, porqué el texto del array se imprime:

> 10987654321Push in array:0

y por qué no se imprime:

> Push in array:012345678910

***Refiriendome al orden*** de como se muestra

Comment: `insertBefore` **inserta antes**

Answer (score 0):

El método [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/insertarAntes)  **inserta antes** del elemento por eso se muestra antes el contenido.

para solucionar podría agregar el contenido como lo estaba realizando empleando [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) , sus ultimas dos líneas serían :

```
 /* .... Código */

 c.appendChild(t);
 w.appendChild(c, lastc);
```

Comment: No me sirve, necesito seguir mostrandolo antes del segundo nodo, pero necesito cambiar el orden de texto en sí

Comment: ¿ En que parte de su pregunta especificó ese detalle ? , qué resultado espera obtener? para así poder darle una mejor respuesta. tiene líneas de código de más.

Comment: Eso quise decir, aparte porque cambiarlo de posicion con insertbefore afecta?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian voy al hecho de que su pregunta es, **por qué muestra este texto antes.**  entonces la respuesta es por el `before` ¿ como solucionar ? lo especifiqué en mi respuesta . más contexto sobre su problema no sé. ¿ Qué resultado desea obtener?